# PyOpenCL returns errors the first run, then only 'invalid program' errors; examples also not working

Tags: python, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, pyopencl

I am trying to run an `OpenCL` kernel using the `pyOpenCL` bindings, to run on the GPU. I was trying to load the kernel to my program. I ran my program once and got an error. I ran it again **without changing the code** and got a different, 'invalid program' error.

This keeps happening to my own programs using `pyOpenCL` and also on example programs. I am able to use `OpenCL` through the `C++` bindings, on both the CPU and GPU, with no problems. So I think this is a problem specific to the `pyOpenCL` bindings.

My OS is Linux Mint 17.1 64 bit. My GPU is an Intel HD graphics 4000 3rd Gen processor. I got the `OpenCL` support for it by installing `beignet` (see [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Beignet/)). I am using `python 2.7` and `OpenCL 1.2`.

The first time I ran my program, I got this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 463, in kernel_call
    self.set_args(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 488, in kernel_set_args
    % (len(args), self.num_args))
AssertionError: length of argument list (4) and CL-generated number of arguments (9) do not agree
```

But then I ran it again, and started getting this *different* error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 206, in _build_and_catch_errors
    raise err
pyopencl.RuntimeError: clBuildProgram failed: invalid program - 

Build on <pyopencl.Device 'Intel HD Graphics Family' on 'Experiment Intel Gen OCL Driver' at 0x7fb77bf21720>:

(options: -I /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/cl)
(source saved as /tmp/tmplLRgy9.cl)
```

I downloaded one of the pyOpenCL examples for [here](https://github.com/pyopencl/pyopencl/tree/master/examples) but I got the same problem: the first time I ran it, I got:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 436, in __getattr__
    return self.event.get_profiling_info(inf_attr)
pyopencl.RuntimeError: clGetEventProfilingInfo failed: profiling info not available
```

...and then I run it again, and I got the same 'invalid program' error from before.

I don't understand why the error changes the second time I run the programs, since I didn't change anything in the code in between runs.

Hope this is clear enough, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it (sort of) by uninstalling `beignet` and installing the latest version, `beignet 1.1.0`, found [here](https://01.org/beignet/downloads).

However, the only way to get the programs to detect my GPU device and work with no problems is by running them as root. Will probably post a different question for that specific issue.

Comment: For future visitors: the new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901160/installed-beignet-to-use-opencl-on-intel-but-opencl-programs-only-work-when-run

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys thank you, should have updated with the link!